# Is it OK for your boss to force you to clean the toilet after you just used it?

Tags: professionalism

Is it normal for your Boss to force you to clean the toilet after you have just used it? I understand that there are some unholy instances where the bathroom can become extremely dirty where cleaning it should be important for the sake of the other employees...

However, and with not becoming too "TMI", I take a serious supplement to help prevent cancers and increase my health. I had went to use the restroom at this new office for the first time, and albeit there was barely a "residue" after I was finished using the restroom. My boss walked in, saw, and commanded me to clean the toilet immediately.

To put this problem into context, there is never an uproar from the boss when there is actual blood in the stall, or on the seats themselves. Am I over reacting, or is this wrong behavior from a boss?

Comment: I've never heard of this before. Is there cleaning staff at this office? Did something get on the seat or somewhere else it could be easily touched?

Comment: It was inside the toilet, and not much there on the inside at that.
We clean based on turns at the end of day day, I don't think we have a dedicated cleaning staff.

Comment: Are you asking if it’s wrong to make you clean the restroom or if it’s wrong for him to hold your residue to a different standard?

Comment: If it is wrong to hold someone's residue to a different standard, when there is barely any to cause an issue

Comment: The way you're talking, it really sounds like you dirtied the toilet with some fairly extreme business (note the "serious supplements" bit, why else would this be mentioned)?  How about this.  Leave the toilet in the same condition you found it.  Can you live with that?  Otherwise it seems like you are trying to rationalize making messes others must clean up.

Answer (score 8):

A generally accepted rule (in Western societies, at least; I've travelled and have actually seen varying standards in developing countries), is to leave the toilets in a state you'd be reasonably ok to find it in. It is, unfortunately, rather theoretical, including in Western societies.

In a workplace context, there often is someone or a company responsible for cleaning the toilets indeed,. So yeah, you kind of have a point... but not necessarily in a small business context... Also...

As to whether you should be asked to do it, most job descriptions include some variation of "and other tasks as assigned." And FWIW I have seen software developers being tasked with cleaning the toilets. (For better or worse. Actually, make that mostly worse.)

Comment: In every business where I've worked, I've always cleaned up the restrooms, especially before customers, would-be employees, or visitors came by. It's part of living in a world populated by humans.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you're the victim of bad timing, and nothing else.

The boss came into the bathroom as you were finishing using the toilet, so could immediately link you to the residue. As Denis mentioned in his answer - many western societies do have a cultural expectation that people leave things like communal toilets and kitchens in a state in which you'd expect you find it. Unfortunately for society, individuals also vary on their expectations.

Those other times where you found residue - well, unless your boss has a habit of waiting to catch every user of the toilet (which would probably be the cause of another question here), then people will get away with not cleaning up after themselves.

You've not been singled out - you've been caught in the act. All that's left to do is get back into the cubicle, scrub that pan, and wash your hands.